# Converting from Activitys to fragments

Tags: android

Hi Im trying to go from an activity to a fragment.

Here's the code that I have in my Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SummaryActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SimpleBookManager testBook = new SimpleBookManager();
        setContentView(R.layout.summary);


        TableLayout tableSummary = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.tableSummary);
        tableSummary.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book2);

        TextView nrOfBooksfield = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.nrOfBooksInCollection);   
        String text = Integer.toString(testBook.count());
        nrOfBooksfield.setText(text);


    }
}
```

And hers my fragment

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class BFragmentTab extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary, container, false);

    }

SimpleBookManager testBook = new SimpleBookManager();
TableLayout tableSummary = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.tableSummary);
tableSummary.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book2);
TextView nrOfBooksfield = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nrOfBooksInCollection);
String text = Integer.toString(testBook.count());
nrOfBooksfield.setText(text);
}
```

Now it complains on `tableSummary.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book2);` saying that it is syntax error on "setBackgroundResource" and the "." Identifier expected.

And there is another error on  `nrOfBooksfield.setText(text);` "misplaced construct on "." and syntaxerror on token "text" VariableDeclarationId expected after this token.

Whats the error, it worked fine in the Activity and now it complains in the fragment (and yes Im a newbie on Android).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inflate a View and place your code inside `onCreateView()`

```
   public class BFragmentTab extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary, 
    SimpleBookManager testBook = new SimpleBookManager();
    TableLayout tableSummary = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tableSummary);
    tableSummary.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book2);
    TextView nrOfBooksfield = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nrOfBooksInCollection);
    String text = Integer.toString(testBook.count());
    nrOfBooksfield.setText(text);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.summary, container, false);
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the code inside the `onActivityCreated` method for instance.

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SimpleBookManager testBook = new SimpleBookManager();
    TableLayout tableSummary = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.tableSummary);
    tableSummary.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book2);
    TextView nrOfBooksfield = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nrOfBooksInCollection);
    String text = Integer.toString(testBook.count());
    nrOfBooksfield.setText(text);
}
```